# How can I move documents between 2 sharepoint 2013 on-premises farms?

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, powershell, sharepoint-rest-api

I have 2 farms inside the same domain and both farms are sharepoint on-premises 2013. Now I want to move documents inside documents libraries from the first farm to the second farm.

Inside the destination farm, I already have a site which have other list and libraries, and I added the related document libraries which mimic the docs libraries inside the source farm.

But I am not sure how I can move the docs from the docs libraries inside the source farm to the destination docs libraries while preserving their properties (such as created, createdby ,modified, modifiedby, title & name). Now all the online documentations I have read show how to move the docs inside the same site collection, using the Content and Structure approach.. but none of them show how to do this cross-farms? I am not sure if this approach which came to my mind should work:-

Using Powershell I can access the source docs using the list API, and then move the documents in a way or another into the destination farm ??

Could any one provide some sample code or adivce on the approach that I can follow?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to just export the library (save the document library / list as a template) if it is small enough. There are additional options available [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166992/copying-a-list-or-document-library-from-one-farm-to-another).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but if i save the list as template, and i add a new list based on the template then all these properties will be changed ; created, created by, modified and modified by. also i do not want to move the whole site as i am not sure what are the modifications that have been made on it by the customer... also i want to move the documents into a site which already have other lists and libraries..

Comment: so i only want to move the documents and preserve their properties...  now can i write a power-shell script which do the copy/paste?? as at the end the documents libraries inside sharepoint are normal libraries storing files... so does power-shell allow me to copy/paste the documents while preserving their original properties?

Comment: If you wrote Powershell script to move files and their properties, you'd still most likely have created by and created dates that were updated based on when you inserted them rather than when they were created on the first site. You can't get around that SharePoint auditing except, perhaps, by importing a template.

Comment: but i have worked on some tasks to move list items inside the same site collection, where i have benefited from the `SystemUpdate()` which allows me to update the list items without changing the modified,created, created by & modified by properties... also one other scenarios i wanted to move list items between sites and i was able to access the list items' versions and create an exact copy of the list items inside new lists... so not sure if i can benefit from these ??

Comment: also when i am inside the same site collection, i can move documents across sites using the Content and Structure approach (the sitemanager.aspx ) page which allow me to move the documents while preserving their original properties.. so i mean saying that `If you wrote Powershell script to move files and their properties, you'd still most likely have created by and created dates that were updated based on when you inserted them rather than when they were created on the first site.` is not the case in sharepoint at-least when moving files inside the same site collection...

Comment: Inside the same site collection, yes. There's a lot of things SharePoint will handle for you in the background and allow a trusted amount of data to be copied with different updates (with user audit and audit time stamps intact), but if you're copying between site collections for security reasons it is basically new (untrusted) data so it generally wouldn't allow you access to the audit time stamps (or people could say documents were there all along when they were in fact added later by an admin).

Comment: so now inside the link you provided one is suggesting to use the Export and Import commands to move the document library? will this work in my case? baring in mind that both farm have different build numbers ? in this case i will be copying the whole library and not the data.. but this is find if i am able to preserve the documents properties?

Comment: When exporting you should be prompted on whether you want to include data (documents, list items, etc) or not. It should recreate in the remote site as is. The problem with doing that with document libraries can be that there is a maximum export/import size for the SP farm. Beyond that limit you have to do Powershell or you have to use a third party application.

Comment: and seems export/import requires both farms to be on the same build number and this is not the case ... now just for testing i tried exporting a document library which have a size of around 170 MB ,, now i have noted that running the export command have produced 7 files of 25 MB each.. so could this solve the problem of maximum size?? although at the end using export/import will not work in my case because both farms have different build numbers...

Comment: It should import without it being the exact same patch level so long as there are hugely different builds or missing dependencies, but you can also crack open the files and edit the version if you're sure the library isn't missing anything to set a specific version number. But at that point, you're getting into a different degree of complexity with this whole solution.

Comment: so you mean the export/import might work even if the farms have different build numbers ?? and what is the worst case if i try to export/import and it fails ?? will it breaks anything ?

Comment: An import that is corrupted or invalid should fail to import and roll itself back as needed w/o issue.

Comment: so do u think that it worth giving it a try to export the list and try to import it into another farm? although the 2 farms have different build numbers; one farm have its build number = "15.0.4569.1000", while the other have this build number = "15.0.4875.1000"?? ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64265/discussion-between-graham-and-john-g).